# Pygame- Disabling a Key with pygame.event.set_blocked() crashes window and returns error

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to add jumping physics to my game but it is necessary that after the player jumps, the Jump-Key has to be disabled until the player lands again.
Now, there isn't any problem with the gravity, but if the player keeps holding K_UP  he could fly forever and the he can fly in a paarabola as he should, so I need to disable jump until the character lands and the jump Loop loops out as expected.
I tried `pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.K_UP)` but when I jump the window crashes and there is an error code: "pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.K_UP) ValueError: event type out of range".

As I couldn't find anything about this command expect that it exists I probablay did an mistake in the Game-Loop using .block().
Here is the Game-Loop

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

         #player1 buttons
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               #move
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 1
                #Jump
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY_change = -3
                player_jump = True
                pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.K_UP)
                if player_jump == True:
                    playerY_change += gravity


        # for X player 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

        #for Y player 1
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if playerY == 900:
                    playerY_change = 0
                    player_jump = False
                    pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.K_UP)
```

I'm new to Pygame (and programming in general) and treid a lot of things and this is the result, so maybe I have also unnecessary code in it. My problem is the part with `pygame.event.set_blocked` and `pygame.event.set_allowed` which I don't know how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.event.set_blocked`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.set_blocked) cannot block a key, it can just block an event such as `KEYDOWN` or `KEYUP`.

Anyway,  you don't have to "block" anything. Uses the Boolean state variable `player_jump` instead:

```py
if not player_jump and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
    playerY_change = -3
    player_jump = True
    playerY_change += gravity
```